# Injecting Web.xml into Spring test context

Tags: spring-integration, spring-test

I am working on unit tests for Web (MVC + Spring integration) application
running on Tomcat.
I am failing to include information stored in web.xml into
Spring Integration test context. Following guidelines from

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.RC1/reference/html/testing.html

I created my JUnit class with the following annotations:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=MyApplicationContext.class)
public class BaseIntegrationUnitTest {...}
```

Class MyApplicationContext is creating Spring integration context for an application:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.xxxxx.search.*")
@PropertySource({"file:${myPropertiesFile}"})
@ImportResource({"classpath:/META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-context.xml"})
public class MyApplicationContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {...}
```

File /META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-context.xml uses some property
that is defined in the file ${myPropertiesFile} which specific location is defined
 in src/resources/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>myPropertiesFile</param-name>
    <param-value>/src/main/resourcses/somePropertiesFile.property</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Attempt to run JUnit test gives error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 
'myPropertiesFile' in string value "file:${myPropertiesFile}"
```

Could anyone give me a hint how to "inject" information from web.xml into
Spring test context?

Comment: Don't. Just set a system property with that value. I also doubt that the location is correct as `src/main/resources` is actually the root of the classpath.

Comment: Setting system property with that value in the class BaseIntegrationUnitTest will not help because class MyApplicationContext will not get it.

Comment: Yes it will you just have to make sure you set it early enough. In a static initializer block (it might even work in a static `@BeforeClass` annotated method.

Comment: But this property is needed in class annotation of MyApplicationContext class which in turn is referred in class annotation of the testing class. Where exactly would you recommend to set the required property?

Comment: As stated in a static initializer block or a `@BeforeClass` method might also work. Those are executed before anything else and as such you can set those properties.

Comment: Thank you very much! Honestly I did not believe that  System.setProperty(...) in a static block would work, I was trying to set property in testing class annotations using @IntegrationTest but it did not help. I did not realize that loading of the class that is in annotation argument actually happens later than testing class is loaded itself.